# dependency for dylibs created by macports

Tags: macos, macros, macports, dylib

I am using macports to install libjpeg in my OS X 9.

The program on my mac runs perfectly fine, but when I install the app on to another mac, I get following error.

```
  Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/ICBE.app/Contents/MacOS/ICBE 
  Reason: image not found
```

I have attached the dylib with build phrases in xcode build settings, so the libjpeg.9.dylib is getting loaded.

My question is, how do I set up macports so the lib won't look for the dylib in /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib but in @rpath/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib

I used otool -L and got following output--

```
Mac-mini-2:~ x2am$ otool -L /master_repo/source/IL/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
/master_repo/source/IL/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib:
/opt/local/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

/opt/local/lib/ is in the one of the paths which is giving problems, but how to solve it?.

Comment: So you're using `libjpeg.9.dylib` within your app?

Comment: yes, i am using it within the app.

Comment: I have previously used `install_name_tool` for similar sort of issue i was getting, but at this moment it seems to be giving error `malformed object (unknown load command 4)`

Comment: I am doing something similar and I had to develop a fairly complicated python script to copy those libraries from `/opt/local/lib` into my app's bundle, and any dependent libraries.  During the copy, the libs are stripped so they are thin x86_64-only and their *Install names* are changed so they load any dependent libraries using `@loader_path/whatever` rather than `/opt/local/lib`.  They are then codesigned.  It's a pretty involved process.

Comment: oh, darn! never done python before. I was wondering if `otool` can be used like `install_name_tool`, to replace the paths inside the lib

Comment: You don't have to use Python, but it will need to be a decent scripting language.  It uses `otool -L` to list dependent libraries, `lipo` to *copy-and-strip* into the app-bundle, `install_name_tool` to fix the location of dependent libraries (and the `id` of a library) and then `codesign` to sign the libraries.  It took me about 5 hours to develop and test.

Comment: Actually in your case, can't you solve this using `install_name_tool -id @loader_path/libjpeg.9.dylib /master_repo/source/IL/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib` ?  That library doesn't appear to have any dependent libraries...

Comment: whatever command i try using `install_name_tool` it says `install_name_tool: for architecture x86_64 object: /master_repo/source/IL/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib malformed object (unknown load command 4)` :(

Comment: OK then the `.dylib` is corrupt I guess.

Comment: no, i tried it with other working dylibs as well.

Comment: If your `install_name_tool` is broken then something is very wrong somewhere.  There is nothing you can do until you get it working again.